# Concepts involved in WS security?

Tags: web-services, security, websphere, soa, ws-security

Please can anyone explain briefly about concepts involved in WS security to protect soap from intermediate web services...

Comment: Can you elaborate on this question a bit more? Perhaps describe the scenarios that concern you in more detail?

Answer (score 5):

WS-Security does not implement anything new. It says how to use XML Encryption and XML Signature specifications in the SOAP world.

WS-Security is transport independent and provides message level security.

Since it's message level security - when we use encryption the message will be encrypted from a key known to the ultimate receiver, so intermediaries cannot view the message.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to provide a simplistic answer unless we know what you are interested in (as Tim mentioned in his comment)

Have a quick read at this to get an idea.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/tutorials/ws-understand-web-services4/

This is not the only reference but think of it as a place to start.

Once you have an idea you will able to ask specific questions and the folks here would be able to help you out with their answers

HTH
Manglu

Answer (score 1):

[JSR 109: Implementing Enterprise Web Services](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=109)

... is also an interesting read. the doc has some further references on the topic.